# Why a separate user for MPI jobs?

Tags: cluster, users, user-accounts

Many of the tutorials on setting up a cluster with MPI suggest creating a separate user with limited permissions ([1](http://byobu.info/articles/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_cluster_with_Ubuntu.html#_configuring_the_nodes), [2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster)). This means running jobs requires logging into a separate user, and is obviously another step.

Why is this necessary, or what does it achieve? Is there any reason *not* to just use the default user?

(We're running this cluster as an educational project: completely offline, with physical access required by known users, so simplicity is preferred over security.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service user allows the principle of least privilege. You can impose quotas or restrictions on the service without impacting the user. Any bad things it may do, like delete the user's files, are limited in scope.

It also is predictable. A standard example for documentation is convenient. You can write an init script for convenience in starting it as a service. A process of that user using lots of resources is expected.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense put this way. If your main user is also the admin, would it still be prudent to "wall off" the work this way, to prevent accidentally deleting something important, etc?

Comment: Sure. An administrator's personal user does not have to be privileged, they can have a regular user and switch with `sudo` or knowing root password. You can run as whatever user you want, just know that there are use cases for personal, service, and privileged super users.